# AngularJS service not setting data correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have this service:

```js
myApp.factory('Auth', function() {
  var user;

  return {
    setUser: function(aUser) {
      user = aUser;
    },
    isLoggedIn: function() {
      return (user) ? user : false;
    }
  }
});
```

And i'm injecting it into my controller "loginCtrl" and setting the user:

```js
myApp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'Auth',
  function($scope, $http, $state, Auth) {
    $scope.login = function() {
      $http.post('/login', $scope.local).success(function(response) {
        Auth.setUser($scope.local);
        console.log(Auth);
        console.log(Auth.user);
        $state.go('news');
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

Auth.setUser never seems to do its job as the console logs immediately after return "Undefined".  What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: try writing an accessor (getUser) function in the factory to return the user variable instead of Auth.user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to your Auth service:

```
getUser: function () {
    return user;
}
```

Otherwise, you can't access variables that are declared within your Auth service, because they are protected. Only items you expose through the return object will be accessible.

```
console.log("User:", Auth.getUser());
```

Comment: Well thats embarrassing. Duh. 

Thanks!